# How to simplify an Excel IF/OR statement

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

How can I simplify this with VLOOKUP or LOOKUP?

```
IF(OR(A1=1,A1=2,A1=3,A1=4,A1=5,A1=6,A1=7),"Yes","No")
```

is there any way to make it more robust using VLOOKUP or any other Excel function to avoid this many or conditions?

Comment: Nothing you have said here suggests you need to use `VLOOKUP` or `LOOKUP` you use those functions if you have a table of data and need to retrieve a value by a key look at the examples here http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php

Comment: You say you don't want to hard ode but you are in the example above. Please be more clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Issun Yes, I dont want to hard code. The above is how I am doing it right now. Want to avoid doing id that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically that OR condition is the same as A1<8 so just do that and get rid of the OR.

`=IF(A1<8,"Yes","No")`

in this example i have a list in Sheet 2 in the A column that contains all the values. In sheet 1 in cell A1 I enter the test number and you can put this formula in any cell you want

`=IF(LOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!A:A)=A1,"Yes","No")`

Comment: The values are not always 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. They can be 1, 23333, 422.2, 888 etc

Comment: Your question is not clear, if your lookup value can be ANY number then you'll need a table that maps each of those numbers against a true or false value then you can do a VLOOKUP and compare the returned value is equal to true or false. This is of course even worse. If you can provide a more accurate use case then perhaps responses will be helpful.

Comment: I have a set of numbers which may change (1,2,3,4,5,6,7...) I want to compare number from Cell A1 to this list of number(again which may change). I don't want to hardcode the values in an IF statement, so am looking for a better way of doing this.

Comment: Okay, in this example i have a list in Sheet 2 in the A column that contains all the values. In sheet 1 in cell A1 I enter the test number and you can put this formula in any cell you want `=IF(LOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:A,Sheet2!A:A)=A1,"Yes","No")`

Answer (score 0):

A bit better:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("|"&A1&"|", "|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|")), "No", "Yes")
```

Assumes no one ever puts "|" into A1

Comment: I want to avoid hard coding of values in formulas, also the values are not always 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. They can be 1, 23333, 422.2, 888 etc

Comment: Well, you can put '|1|23333|422.2|888|' there, too.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same:

```
=IF(AND(A1>0,A1<8,INT(A1)=A1),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: The values are not always 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. They can be 1, 23333, 422.2, 888 etc

Comment: they would evaluate to 'No' in your function as well then. If any value >0 and less than <8 is what you want then just remove the ,INT(A1)=A1

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you have a value in cell, say A1, and a variety of other values in cells B1:B8 and you'd like to know whether A1 matches any value present in B1:B8.

You could set up a flag variable taking value 1 if a match is found and 0 if not as follows:
 =1-ISNA(MATCH(A1,B1:B8,0))

Alternatively, you could do something like:
 =IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,B1:B8,0)),"No","Yes") to output something more similar to the above.